# what are the image formats that can be used to create a texture in opengles?

Tags: opengl-es

I had recently starting learning openGLES and right now I had gone through some tutorials,so when I had come across the  texture mapping concept  am having a doubt that what are all the image formats we can use to create a texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most image formats need conversion before they can be used as textures. There are libraries (e.g., [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/)) to handle that though. Without something to handle the conversion, the answer is basically "none". With DevIL, the answer becomes "nearly anything."

Comment: thx a lot jerry,this info is really helpful to me to find out my way.now for example can we convert the images with the formats like unity,eps e.t.c by using these existing libraries.?

Comment: EPS has to be rasterized before much of anything can deal with it as a texture. Rasterize to TIFF (or whatever) and that'll be easy to use. I don't know of much other than Unity's own engine that works with their files (though I've never looked very hard either...)

Comment: sure jerry will try to explore regarding that and really thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge with a beginner like me.

Comment: hi jerry i started working with textures and now am facing a small problem with it.that is am not able to map all the textures to the objects,to be clear am using a png file and creating a texture with it.till here everything goes fine but i dono what's the problem in texture mapping only few files with .png formats are working fine plz help me to fix this issue.thx in adv.

Comment: @ravoorinandan: offhand, I'm not at all sure. You *could* just be hitting the limits on how many textures your graphics card supports. What errors are you getting when it fails? You might be better off asking this as a new question too -- even though I don't have an answer right off, somebody else might (somebody who might not notice a comment added to a week-old question).

Comment: yeah jerry sure i'll post this as a new question and more over am not getting any error. i.e when i create a texture and map it to the object,it simply renders the plain object without any texture mapped on it,thats it and even i checked by using the debugger but it was of no use!